# Excel table columns stopped auto resizing after power query refresh, and I want them to auto resize

Tags: excel, powerquery

This is the opposite problem to everyone else on the internet.
In the distant past I have unticked the "Adjust column width" setting in the external data properties box when I didn't want the column width to change.

Now I generally don't untick the box and let the columns change width as the data changes.

But for some reason I have a workbook where suddenly the auto resize column width has stopped working for all the power query driven tables? What has gone wrong?

Any ideas? Thanks

Comment: click on the table and go to menu Table design > properties. is the "Adjust column width " option checked?

Comment: Yes! I have no idea what is wrong...